# how to sending a message(embed) to a spesific channel. Discord.js V12

Tags: discord, discord.js

So I made a simple message embed and it works, this is my code:

```
client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.content === 'hi!') {
      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("RANDOM")
      .setDescription('hello there!')
      .setTimestamp()
  
      message.channel.send(embed)
    }
    
  })
```

I want the bot to only reply with this embed in a specific channel

For example:
If I send a message in channel 'A', it replies but if I I send a message in channel 'B' it doesn’t send anything.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t create a channel id, it is already defined in channel.id

If you want the bot to only read messages in a specific channel you can use message.channel.id and an if statement:

```
client.on('message', async message => {
  if (message.channel.id === '<id of the channel you want>') {
    if (message.content === 'hi!') {
      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("RANDOM")
      .setDescription('hello there!')
      .setTimestamp()
    
      message.channel.send(embed)
    }
  }
})
```